# SignalR does not connect when i record it with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, signalr, performance-testing

Hi I am doing performance testing over a application but i cannot replicate the signalR connection what i do is call to the negociate api

/signalr/negociate getting the response as expected with the connection token

```
"Url":"/MyApp/signalr","ConnectionToken":"gM8NUnZtDg6oYU3Y9sfZgnIDlInyvspePwDuRdmqZlslRgkPIp8w/c0FZzllhwiUdZlOmPkyBd2DGU76ldt3v1B25lQlTeg1jETBWRkqaXD0QGpeNJLl3KqvnJ3v4YQ2","ConnectionId":"e1adc41d-ad0d-439f-858c-1fa47bb59083","KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,"DisconnectTimeout":30.0,"ConnectionTimeout":110.0,"TryWebSockets":true,"ProtocolVersion":"1.5","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,"LongPollDelay":0.0}
```

Then i extract with JMeter that token (and i use it into the connect call)

```
GET https://myHost/myApp/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=gM8NUnZtDg6oYU3Y9sfZgnIDlInyvspePwDuRdmqZlslRgkPIp8w%2Fc0FZzllhwiUdZlOmPkyBd2DGU76ldt3v1B25lQlTeg1jETBWRkqaXD0QGpeNJLl3KqvnJ3v4YQ2&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22workhub%22%7D%5D&tid=2
```

But the response is always a 400 Bad Request

Not a valid web socket request.

Any idea why that call fail?

Thank you very much

Comment: Update: If i execute the /myApp/signalr/start with the same token the response it is success -> { "Response": "started" }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can record WebSocket requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as the aforementioned HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is only capable of generating [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers as of [JMeter 5.2](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-released-td5728631.html)

I would recommend using one of the following approaches for capturing outgoing WebSocket requests:

- [Browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) (network tab should have WebSocket traffic filtering option)
- [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/forums/capture-localhost-websocket-traffic)
- [Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/WebSocket)

Once done you can install [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers) plugin and [use the appropriate Samplers to simulate the WebSocket requests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide/), you will need to manually set up the payload.